# I can't understand how to identify in my treeView1 if a node is a file or a directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is how i'm adding the nodes to the TreeNode:

```
private int total_dirs;
        private int searched_until_now_dirs;
        private int max_percentage;
        private TreeNode directories_real_time;
        private string SummaryText;

        private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(string path, string name , int recursive_levl )
        {
            var directoryNode = new TreeNode(name);
            var directoryListing = GetDirectoryListing(path);

            var directories = directoryListing.Where(d => d.IsDirectory);
            var files = directoryListing.Where(d => !d.IsDirectory);

            total_dirs += directories.Count<FTPListDetail>();
            searched_until_now_dirs++;

            int percentage;

            foreach (var dir in directories)
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(dir.FullPath, dir.Name, recursive_levl+1));

                if (recursive_levl == 1)
                {
                    TreeNode temp_tn = (TreeNode)directoryNode.Clone();

                    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker( delegate
                    {
                        UpdateList(temp_tn);
                    }));
                }


                percentage = (searched_until_now_dirs * 100) / total_dirs;
                if (percentage > max_percentage)
                {
                    SummaryText = String.Format("Searched dirs {0} / Total dirs {1}", searched_until_now_dirs, total_dirs);
                    max_percentage = percentage;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage, SummaryText);
                }
            }

            percentage = (searched_until_now_dirs * 100) / total_dirs;
            if (percentage > max_percentage)
            {
                SummaryText = String.Format("Searched dirs {0} / Total dirs {1}", searched_until_now_dirs, total_dirs);
                max_percentage = percentage;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage, SummaryText);
            }

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
                numberOfFiles.Add(file.FullPath);
            }           

            return directoryNode;
        }
```

Then i'm updating the treeView1:

```
DateTime last_update;

        private void UpdateList(TreeNode tn_rt)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - last_update;
            if (ts.TotalMilliseconds > 200)
            {
                treeView1.BeginUpdate();
                treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn_rt);
                TreeViewXmlPopulation.SerializeTreeView(treeView1, @"c:\XmlFile\Test.xml");
                ExpandToLevel(treeView1.Nodes, 1);
                treeView1.EndUpdate();
            }

        }
```

In the end when i see the directories and files structure in the treeView1 i want to know when i select an item with the mouse if it's a directory or a file.

The directories and files in the treeView1 i get them from my ftp server.

[image: TreeView1]

For example if i click on A i want to know that i selected a directory and if i click on install.exe i want to know that it's a file.

This is how i select an item in the treeView1:

```
private void treeView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

                if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
                {
                    menuStrip.Show(treeView1, e.Location);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have a context menu strip with options:

```
private void menuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Delete")
            {
                Delete(treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath);
            }
        }
```

In the FullPath it can be just a single file or a directory name with or without files inside.
How do i know if it's a file or a directory ? In the Delete method i want to decide what to do if it's a file then delete a file and if it's a directory then do something else.

I thought to use Tag propert but not sure how to use it. I tried to add in the CreateDirectoryNode this:

```
directoryNode.Tag = directoryNode.Nodes;
```

But i'm not sure if it's the right way to do it and how to use the Tag later to identify if it's file or directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution:

first save the root as a full dir (directly in the name or some string in background)
second once you click on a node get its full name `node.FullPath`
is this way you'll get a string that is the full path that this node represents (directory of file )
now as **Scott Nimrod** allready sed check if it is a file or dir using

```
!System.IO.Directory.Exists(node.FullPath) //==> yep this is a file
```

take a look of this example(from my project that iterate over recursivly and create a tree)

this example will iterate over and look for special extention

```
        public TreeNode RecursiveDirToTree(TreeNode parentNode, string path,
                                 string extension = ".txt")
    {
        var result = new TreeNode(parentNode == null ? path/*base line*/ : System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
        foreach (string dir in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            TreeNode node = RecursiveDirToTree(result, dir , extension);
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                result.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
        }
        foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower() == extension.ToLower())
            {
                result.Nodes.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tag is ok, because it is unused prpoerty per default and it is really a property, which does not bother with being abused . The type is object. So it takes everything. But YOU MUST TAKE CARE YOURSELF for putting something in it and retrieve it properly.

Best way to do so is to save a list inside tag, which consists of two columns , type and reference.
But for Your case just put the nodes into tag and then retrieve them with a proper cast into a local object.
By the way, you also might want to load subdirs just in demand, in order to check, whether it is file or dir.
this can optimize performance.

Answer (score 1):

File.Exists and Directory.Exists